# Find and replace a value in google sheet via Java API V4

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I would like to find a value and replace it to another value in google sheet using the Java API.

This is my code, but it only changes the value upon the index and column I refer to it.

```
requests.add(new Request()
    .setCopyPaste(new CopyPasteRequest()
        .setSource(new GridRange()
            .setSheetId(0)
            .setStartRowIndex(0)
            .setEndRowIndex(1)
            .setStartColumnIndex(0)
            .setEndColumnIndex(3))
        .setDestination(new GridRange()
            .setSheetId(0)
            .setStartRowIndex(1)
            .setEndRowIndex(6)
            .setStartColumnIndex(0)
            .setEndColumnIndex(3))
        .setPasteType("PASTE_FORMAT")));
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
    .setRequests(requests);
```

Comment: Can you please provide input and output you get and you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `FindReplaceRequest()` to do this

```
        requests.add(new Request().setFindReplace(new FindReplaceRequest().setFind(entry.getKey())
                .setMatchEntireCell(true)
                .setMatchCase(true)
                .setReplacement(entry.getValue())
                .setRange(new GridRange()
                        .setSheetId(0)
                        .setStartRowIndex(row)
                        .setEndRowIndex(row + 1))));
    }



    String cellReq = (new FindReplaceRequest().setFind("samuel")).getFind();
```